# 410 Gone - Images are on right directory

Tags: image, jsp, webserver, http-status-code-410

On my site some of my products picture are not shown.
When i right click to inspect element and click my pictures url there is written

**410 GONE**

When i refresh the site image is shown.
I have lots of products so pictures too on my site and thats a big problem for me.

Thanks for helping.

```
<div class="productGallery"> <img id="product" width="450" height="405" src="http://www.mydomain.com.tr/files/data/OrgImage/v2/<c:out value="${prdPictureOrj}"/>_1b.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://www.mydomain.com.tr/files/data/OrgImage/v2/<c:out value="${prdPictureOrj}"/>_1b.jpg" /> 
    <a href="#" class="openLightbox"></a> <c:if test="${prdDemo != ''}"><a onclick="OpenTv();" class="watch"></a></c:if>
      <div id="productGallery"> 
      <a href="#" data-image="http://www.mydomain.com.tr/files/data/OrgImage/v2/<c:out value="${prdPictureOrj}"/>_1b.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://www.mydomain.com.tr/files/data/OrgImage/v2/<c:out value="${prdPictureOrj}"/>_1b.jpg"> <img  onerror="this.src='assets/images/nophoto-140x125.jpg'" id="img_01" src="http://www.mydomain.com.tr/files/data/OrgImage/v2/<c:out value="${prdPictureOrj}"/>_1b.jpg" width="70" height="70" /> </a> 
      <a href="#" data-image="http://www.mydomain.com.tr/files/data/OrgImage/v2/<c:out value="${prdPictureOrj}"/>_2b.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://www.mydomain.com.tr/files/data/OrgImage/v2/<c:out value="${prdPictureOrj}"/>_2b.jpg"> <img  onerror="this.src='assets/images/nophoto-140x125.jpg'" id="img_01" src="http://www.mydomain.com.tr/files/data/OrgImage/v2/<c:out value="${prdPictureOrj}"/>_2b.jpg" width="70" height="70" /> </a> 
      <a href="#" data-image="http://www.mydomain.com.tr/files/data/OrgImage/v2/<c:out value="${prdPictureOrj}"/>_3b.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://www.mydomain.com.tr/files/data/OrgImage/v2/<c:out value="${prdPictureOrj}"/>_3b.jpg"> <img  onerror="this.src='assets/images/nophoto-140x125.jpg'" id="img_01" src="http://www.mydomain.com.tr/files/data/OrgImage/v2/<c:out value="${prdPictureOrj}"/>_3b.jpg" width="70" height="70" /> </a> 
      <a href="#" data-image="http://www.mydomain.com.tr/files/data/OrgImage/v2/<c:out value="${prdPictureOrj}"/>_4b.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://www.mydomain.com.tr/files/data/OrgImage/v2/<c:out value="${prdPictureOrj}"/>_4b.jpg"> <img  onerror="this.src='assets/images/nophoto-140x125.jpg'" id="img_01" src="http://www.mydomain.com.tr/files/data/OrgImage/v2/<c:out value="${prdPictureOrj}"/>_4b.jpg" width="70" height="70" /> 
      <a onclick="OpenTv();" class="tv_icon"></a></a>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide some context or source code? How are the pictures displayed and are the URLs hardcoded or do you have some generator?

Comment: Some of my pictures are Shown some of arent.
ıs it enough for you to share my code which include about pictures ?

Comment: Yes the code snippet where the images are shown should be sufficient. But I don't know yet if I know the answer.

Comment: I added my code above.